# Icon Color in Android Slide Menu

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I am looking for a way to define the color of different icons in the Slide Out menu of Android . I have searched a lot on this site but could not find any answer to my specific question .
So I have three items in my slide out menu . Each item has a text and an icon . I want to give a different color to each of these icons at design time. I have been able to give a ***single*** color to all these icons using the following code

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 //Some more code here
 app:itemIconTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
```

This gives a single uniform color to all the icons but this is not what I want . I want each of the menu icons to have their own color .

1) I have tried the following -

```
<item android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
      android:title="Camera"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
      android:iconTint="@color/colorAccent">
</item>
```

2) I have also tried to change the color in the vector definition of ic_camera . This approach also does not work .

The icon color always remains gray and does not respond to any of the above code changes .

Can someone please help me with this .

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below line after declaring navigation View:

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: This will do the job. Happy Coding bro !

Answer (score 0):

**Use a custom style:**

```
<style name="yourIconStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

*and then set it to your item:-*

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIconStyle</item>
```